# PyCharm: How to change the font size without zooming with mouse scroll?

Tags: ide, settings, pycharm

As the title says, how can I change the font size in the editor by some value? I like the scrolling thing, but the problem is I have to scroll again and every time I open an IDE again.

I found the settings for changing the value of the font size, but it's disabled. Do I have to pay for that feature?

Answer (score 76):

- version 2017.1 and older -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Font`
- since 2017.2 -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor |  Color Scheme | Color Scheme Font`

> I found the settings for changing the value of the font size, but it's disabled.

It's disabled because it is not allowed to edit **bundled** scheme. [To "enable" it just **create your own scheme based on any of the bundled ones**](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html) (click the "Save As" button next to Scheme Name):

[image]

Once you've done that you can alter any of the color/style settings.

---

If you have somehow increased (or decreased) the font size dynamically via shortcut then just use the **"Reset Font Size" action**. You can assign any shortcut to those actions at `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`:

[image]

You can also call that action directly via `Help | Find Action...`:

[image]

Comment: File | Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Font

Comment: Note -- if you are **currently zoomed in/out**, you will need to either close + reopen the file you are viewing, or **Shift+ CMD + A -> Reset default font size** per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/zooming-in-the-editor.html before seeing the updated default font size

Answer (score 11):

### Adding Keyboard Shortcut for font zooming pycharm

1. **File** --> **Settings** .
2. Select **keymap**.
3. Search for  **Increase font size** and **Decrease font size** and add **New Keyboard Shortcut** .

   *Make sure that the shortcut you selected do not effect other shortcuts.*
4. Done .

Answer (score 8):

### Quick Answer:

Tested on version **2018/2017**:

1. **File** ➜ **Settings...**
2. In left side expand **Editor** ➜ **Font**
3. Change **Size** value.
4. <kbd>**Apply**</kbd> + <kbd>**OK**</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

For Pycharm, it is in settings->editer->General->Mouse->Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel.

Comment: Basically what I already commented on @Gouranga Satapathy's answer. The question seems to be exactly about how to do that without using the Mouse Wheel, so the setting is probably already enabled in the asker's case and it probably is not that relevant to his case, which is to set a numeric default value to which the editor's font size will be set to whenever opening PyCharm.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac

To edit Font size, do the following:

Click **PyCharm** | **Preferences** from the main menu, and then go to **Editor** | **Font**.

Answer (score 2):

Using shortcut
In windows Ctrl+Alt+S brings Setting window for Pycharm straightaway, then on left hand side you can click on font tab, and increase or decrease size of font as you like. It changes font size of code that you actually write inside PyCharm IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom theme you may need to do it in the theme's settings page.
Editor -> Color Scheme -> Color Scheme Font

Answer (score 0):

- Basic info:

- Mac air(m1),mac os:big Sur,11.3.1
- pycharm:2021.1.3

- Ways:

- pycharm->preference->Editor->General->Font->
- Size, line height ->
- Apply.

Comment: Does this help when `the settings for changing the value of the font size [are] disabled`?

Comment: It's disabled because it is not allowed to edit bundled scheme. To "enable" it just create your own scheme based on any of the bundled ones (click the "Save As" button next to Scheme Name):

enter image description here

Once you've done that you can alter any of the color/style settings.

Comment: That side-step approach was added by LazyOne to his [2014 explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22933453/3789665) in September 2015. I think the keyboard shortcut more direct, if less persistent - the question was *with out zooming with mouse scroll*, not *once and for all* or 'for good*.

Comment: As far as I know, there are two ways to set the font size of the editing area.
1.Set the default font size
That is, every time the software is opened, the font size of the written code is the set value.
2.mouse control
Ctrl+Mouse Wheel
Commond+Mouse
3.Make sure the pycharm software you are currently using is activated